# How would I find out why selenium is following a link that is not in a test?

Tags: perl, selenium

I have several tests that continually follow a link that is not in the test.

One of my test files follows this particular link so I thought that perhaps
the server was caching the link ('/settings').  So, I restarted the server
and ran the tests without the /settings link and it's still going to the /settings
link.

```
$sel->click_ok('//a[contains(@href, /settings)]');
```

is continually being followed even though it's only in one of the test files.
It's (/settings) even followed when the link is

```
$sel->is_element_present_ok('//a[contains(@href, /marketing/calendar)]');
```

Anyone know why this would be happening?

Edit:

The test is passing for the /marketing/calender link.

```
ok 13 - click, //a[contains(@href, /marketing/calender)]
```

But when the page loads, it's loading the /settings page so the subsequent
is_text_present_ok tests are failing.

Comment: Sounds like you've got an application bug.  There's no way Selenium is doing that for/to you.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I wasn't doing $sel->open_ok('/marketing/calendar');  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't doing $sel->open_ok('/marketing/calendar'); after
$sel->click_ok('//a[contains(@href, /settings)]');

Following the click_ok() with the open_ok() appeared to solve the problem.